# Excel create a new chart for every 10 rows ( 2 columns)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns with the numbers and 854 rows ( 2 columns A and B - 854 rows populated with numbers).

I would like to create a new line chart for every 10 rows (A and B columns), so in total 85 full charts and one with 4 rows of data, placed one below another one.

the expected result would be 86 charts on a sheet, something like this:

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Welcome! Such a macro takes about 20 lines of code and costs about $70 on the freelance exchange. What part of this macro have you already written?

Comment: @JohnSUN is it possible to do it without VBA?

Comment: Of course it's possible - just 86 times select range of 20 cells, insert chart, set size and position, repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do it manually - a computer is needed to make life easier for a person, not complicate it:

```
Sub makeCharts()
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim oChart As Shape
    Set oSheet = ActiveSheet
    For iRow = 1 To 854 Step 10
        Set oChart = oSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlLineMarkers)
        With oChart.Chart
            .SetSourceData Source:=oSheet.Range("A" & iRow & ":B" & (iRow + 9))
            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesMajor)
        End With
        With Range("C" & iRow & ":F" & (iRow + 9))
            oChart.Left = .Left
            oChart.Top = .Top
            oChart.Width = .Width
            oChart.Height = .Height
        End With
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: this works great, thank you, how would you set this to be one chart directly under another one, ie. if the steps are 100, not 10, there would be much blank space inbetween the charts, what to change here: With Range("C" & iRow & ":F" & (iRow + 9)) so they are with less blank space in between.

Comment: 9 is count of rows between first and last row of range (10-1=9, 20-11=9, etc.) Change it as you need